# Which part of a Union type does a value satisfy?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic-v2

I'm using the Typing module and Pydantic to define a custom type which is a union. How can I tell which part of the Union is satisfied by a particular value after initializing the class?

For example, in:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union, Literal, Tuple, List

from pydantic import BaseModel, UUID4, ValidationError


class ExportDataRequest(BaseModel):
    customers: Union[Literal["all"], List[UUID4], UUID4, List[int], int]
    daterange: Union[Tuple[datetime, datetime], int]


data = {
    "customers": "all",
    'daterange': ("2024-01-01", "2024-03-01")
}

try:
    model = ExportDataRequest(**data)
    
    print(type(model.customers))
    # str
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e.errors())
```

The type from the `Union` satisfied by the input to `customers` above is the `Literal["all"]` piece.

If I ask for the `type` of `model.customers` as in the above snippet, python will respond with `str`.

Is there a way to determine that it is the `Literal["all"]` from my class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who sees this, I solved it with Pydantic's `TypeAdapter`: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/type_adapter/

Adding the below to the code from the question above:

```py
from pydantic import TypeAdapter

def handle_type(model):
    types_to_check = [
        (Literal["all"], "all"),
        (List[UUID4], "uuid_list"),
        (List[int], "int_list"),
        (int, "int"),
        (UUID4, "uuid"),
    ]

    for type_to_check, result in types_to_check:
        try:
            TypeAdapter(type_to_check).validate_python(model.customers)
            return result
        except ValidationError:
            pass

    return None
```